# Julia FITSIO: modify FITS header keyword and save to file

Tags: julia, astronomy

I try to modify a keyword in the header of a FITS file and then save the change. Here is what I do:

```
using FITSIO
imhdulist = FITS("myfile.fits")
imheader=read_header(imhdulist[1])
imheader["FILTER"]="r"
close(imhdulist)
```

But the header of file is unchanged. How can I save the changes to the input file?

Comment: When you open a file via FITS, it seems the default is opening it in "r" mode. You are able to pass "r+" mode for read/write. That may be it. See towards the end of https://julia-fitsio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Either that, or you're not meant to "change" files. Maybe you just change the header *in memory*, and you can "write" the whole thing to a new FITS file to replace the old one?  (disclaimer: I don't use FITS :p )

Comment: I tried to open the file in read-write mode as suggested but still no luck... I guess you are right and it is not possible to replace the input file... I wonder what that read-write mode means then... Let's see if someone has an idea?

Comment: well, presumably it means you can *append* more data.

Comment: So it seems the only way is to open a new file to save the changes. I simply overwrite the input file and it does the trick.